# How to duplicate a subquery in FROM Clause to 2 Alias for Self Join?

Tags: mysql, subquery, alias

I want to use the result of a subquery twice or more for SELF JOIN in MySQL, is there a solution for this issue or anything like that, i.e temporary table or somewhat?
Thanks you.

Comment: try CTE.   `with tblName As`

Comment: I'm sorry, but i'm woking with MySQL, it doesn't support CTE :(

Comment: If you want to use the result set more than once, you can use temp table or table variables. If you wanna use it just once, try sub-query, drived table or inline views.

Answer (score 0):

Create a view for it and use the view name in your JOIN.

No matter how many times you want to use it in your query, MySQL will have to execute each of them individually. No computing cost can be saved.

No matter using VIEW or alias, the multiple times of calculation are always needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
with subQuery AS (select something from tblName where something = happened)
```

then you can

```
select * from subQuery A join subQuery B on A.zig = B.zag
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention I'm using MySQL :(